# jquery mentionsInput with newly generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an element newly added to my DOM. I want to use [jquery.mentionsInput](https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input) to discover `@string` style mentions in its content. I am also using JQuery and Underscore, because they are dependencies for mentionsInput. How do I do that?

I have this code, but it doesn't do what I want:

```js
$('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({
  onDataRequest: function (mode, query, callback) {
    var data = [
      { id: 1, name: 'First Name' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Second Name' }
    ]
    data = _.filter(data, function(item) {
     return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf( query.toLowerCase() ) > -1
    })
    callback.call(this, data)
  }
})
```

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Comment: sorry  i didn't get you , i'm new in jquery @Swati

Comment: how that textarea gets generated ? You can show working example for that .

Comment: when i click at new  button i call method create_new() inside this method i use bootbox dialog to view form that i need in adding new element ,this form  i genereted it as String , and put this string in bootbox message , textarea inside the form

Comment: function create_new_notification() {
    TableTools.fnGetInstance('editable').fnSelectNone();
    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
        title: '<span lang="en">New Notification</span>',
        message: get_form_data('add_notification', ''),
        buttons: {
            success: {
               
            },
            cancel: {
                label: '<span lang="en">Cancel</span>',
                className: 'btn-default'
            }
        }
    });
}

Comment: get_form_data('add_notification' ) this return generated form inside this form there is textearea

Comment: You can intialize newly created textarea inside `create_new_notification()` .So , last line of that function you can write `$('textarea.mention:last').mentionsInput(..allsame..` this will intialize textarea which is added last to your dom.

Comment: Thanks a million  @Swati, it worked  finally :) you can add your comment as an answer

Comment: Your welcome and you can answer your own question :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by initializing newly created textarea inside function that add this new textarea element to my  DOM.So , last line of that function I wrote

$('textarea.mention:last').mentionsInput(....etc